# How many invertible functions exist for a prime order group?

Tags: abstract-algebra, combinatorics, number-theory, elementary-set-theory

Suppose you have a group with prime order $n = 257$.

For a given integer $k$, we can find:

- Additive inverses: $-k$ mod 257
- Multiplicative inverses: $k^{255}$ mod 257
- Square roots via Tonelli-Shanks

I am curious, are there any other such functions that are invertible like this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking - There are $257!$ bijections on $\mathbb Z / 257 \mathbb Z$. Among them are the three you describe.

Comment: Hello, thank you for the comment. I am new to abstract algebra, can you please elaborate or point me to some resources to understand what you mean? How would I determine these other bijections?

Comment: This is pure combinatorics. I will write this in an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We only need that the group $G = \mathbb Z / 257 \mathbb Z$ has 257 elements. The question then reads:

> How many bijections are there between $G$ and itself?

We can think about this as follows. Pick an element $x_1$ of $G$. Then we have to map $x_1$ to some element $y_1$. To do this, we have $257$ choices. Now pick a second element $x_2$, which gets mapped to $y_2$. In order to ensure that our map $x_i \mapsto y_i$ we are constructing will be a bijection, we cannot let $y_2 = y_1$, but any other element is okay. So we have 256 choices, for a total of $257 \cdot 256$ choices till now. Next, for $x_3$, we have $255$ choices. Continuing like this, the last element $x_{257}$ must be mapped to the single element $y_{257}$ we have not hit yet. Thus, the number of possible bijections of $G$ is
$$257! = 257 \cdot 256 \cdot 255 \cdots 3 \cdot 2 \cdot 1.$$

Comment: Thank you! I guess the misunderstanding was that I assumed multiplication and addition were separate operations when in reality, multiplication is just repeated addition and squaring is just repeated multiplication. Everything you said here makes perfect sense.

Comment: In fact, they can be considered as separate operations. Moreover, the two bijections you found using them are actually distinct ($-1 = 256$ in your group, whereas $1^{-1} = 1$).

Answer (score 0):

Assume $G$ is a group of order $257$ written multiplicatively.

- The $k \mapsto k^n$ is invertible iff $257$ does not divide $n$. In particular, for all $n=1,2,\dots, 256$.
- Fix $g \in G$. Then the map $k \mapsto gk$ is invertible.